# how to install ubuntu-SDK in ubuntu 14.04 64bit?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk

i would like to install Ubuntu-SDK in my system.i tried to follow this site [this site](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-sdk/installing-the-sdk/)

but i getting the error called package-dependency.i think that link is old.so any body know another way to install it?
Thanks regards,

Comment: What error did you get exactly?

Comment: i just reinstall ubuntu 15.04 now everything works fine.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I followe the same tuto, but it workedfor me. Although I cannot compile anything because of some dependencies, but Te sdk is installed.